# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS 8 only when popToViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, exc-bad-access

Ive been working on  this problem for the past week and I have not been able to solve it. I was able to find where specifically the exception was being thrown from the help of some stack overflow advice using Zombie process and found that when i do a `popToViewController` in iOS 8 for some reason iOS 8 looses something in my flow but i have no idea what it is. I think it may have to do with the `navigationController` and I've tried various ways to `popToViewController`. 
**My question** is if anyone sees what the culprit might be in the below code ALSO is there a better way to pop to a view controller for iOS 8 users. The crash occurs  when the user is back at View 2 and presses on any button in the view whether it be a `UIButton` that moves to another view or tries to move back using the `navigationButton`.
The flow is this: **View 1 --> View 2 --> View 3 --> View 4 === View 4** pops back to **View 2**:

VIEW 4: `ChooseTempatureViewController`:

```
Class classToPopTo = [BuildTempatureViewController class];
        for (UIViewController *view in [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectEnumerator]) {
            if([view class] == classToPopTo){
                NSLog(@"%s STARTED POP TO", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:view animated:YES];
                return;
            }
        }
```

View 2 : `TempatureViewController`:

Press any button and receive `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and with zombie process enabled it gave me this as the Zombie

```
[TempatureViewController navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x86d67720
```

Any Advice to help my iOS 8 users would be greatly appreciated, project is using `ARC`
Also I'm using `XIBs`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any other solution, like using Unwind Segue. Here is an example: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/04/23/unwind-segue-set-destination/. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to supply an answer. I should have mentioned that I'm using XIBs and not storyboards. Eventually I'd like to convert to storyboard